# mvvm in wpf - Action is fired by which control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

two button (buttonA and buttonB) are binded with single Icommand (StartPuzzleCommand ).

```
  startPuzzleCommand = new DelegateCommand(delegate()
                {
                   // which control fire this action

                });
```

now the question is how can i get which button call the delegate on click..
Well this is my second day of learning mvvm,please suggest some help;
i am using CommandReference.cs and DelegateCommand.cs predefined classes......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
startPuzzleCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(
    delegate(string which)
    {

    });
```

And in your XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="buttonA"
        Command="{Binding StartPuzzleCommand}"
        CommandParameter="A" />

<Button x:Name="buttonB"
        Command="{Binding StartPuzzleCommand}"
        CommandParameter="B" />
```

Comment: thanx alot buddy,i havent tested this till now,but i knew it will work,thankx buddy

Comment: one thing can i pass the complete object of button under command parameter like

Comment: <Button x:Name="buttonB"                                 Command="{Binding StartPuzzleCommand}"         CommandParameter="buttonB" />

Comment: @slash: You can pass any string you'd like :)

Comment: ok,is there is a way i can get the complete object of button,,, like sender in button_click event

Comment: @slash: not sure why you'd like to do it that way, but if you change it to `DelegateCommand<object>` and `CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=buttonA}"`, it *may* work.

Comment: i was thinking in very same way,let me try

Answer (score 0):

Why are you binding the buttons with same command? Only solution would be to bind each button click event with different command.

Comment: well i am having 11 buttons all have same implementation almost based on the button name....

Comment: hmm then I guess sixlettervariables's answer will work in your case